# locating pywin32 library components python

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

Hello I am using pywin32 to track several actions on server, currently i am looking to track the files open per user on server, well I found `File_Info_Structure_3`, here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, but i cannot find it in any of the pywin32 libraries, i checked in `win32net`, in `win32file` but it is not there. Does anyone know how i can import and use it. Thanks!

What I am getting:

```
{'num_locks': 0, 'path_name': u'd:\\database\\agdata\\inx\\', 'user_name': u'finance', 'id': -1342162944, 'permissions': 1}
{'num_locks': 0, 'path_name': u'd:\\database\\dealdata\\', 'user_name': u'ntmount', 'id': 1879102464, 'permissions': 1}
{'num_locks': 0, 'path_name': u'd:\\database\\dealdata\\', 'user_name': u'ntmount', 'id': 536973312, 'permissions': 1}
{'num_locks': 0, 'path_name': u'd:\\database\\agdata\\inx\\', 'user_name': u'ntmount', 'id': -469590016, 'permissions': 1}
..........
```

What I need:

```
{'num_locks': 0, 'path_name': u'd:\\database\\agdata\\inx\\', '10.2.2.3': u'finance', 'id': -1342162944, 'permissions': 1}
{'num_locks': 0, 'path_name': u'd:\\database\\dealdata\\', '10.5.3.23': u'ntmount', 'id': 1879102464, 'permissions': 1}
..........
```

Answer (score 0):

The FILE_INFO_* structs were not translated into python equivalents. They will be returned or used, e.g. by [win32net.NetFileEnum](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32net__NetFileEnum_meth.html) as a dictionary.

Comment: Because i want to find the computer name which opened the file, but i will put what i am getting in the question.

Comment: As described in the documentation, the result of (for example) `NetFileEnum` is a list of the FILE_STRUCT_* dictionaries, which can be simply accessed by the key names of the struct attributes. Maybe it would help you, if you just `print` the result of the win32net function into the console or testing this out of your python interpreter shell. Then you can see how the dict has been build up.

Comment: But how can i get an ip address instead of `user_name`.

Comment: ... but ... I'm not really sure if FILE_INFO_3 contains the information about the computername you are searching for -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx has just only: *id, permissions, num_locks, pathname, username

Comment: You mean: *you want to find out the host (IP) which have accessed/connected/logged into the computer with the given username*?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i want to find.

Comment: Maybe win `win32net.NetSessionEnum(502)` and `win32net.netFileEnum(3)`, somehow corrolate the two.

Comment: With `win32security.LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` you are able to find all logged in user sessions and with `win32security.LsaGetLogonSessionData(logonSessionId)` you will get more information about each of them. The returned structure is following one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and should contains a dictionary key named *LogonServer* with your needed information and with *UserName* you can identify the correct session data.

Comment: It still doesn't display the destination of files openend

Comment: What exactly doesn't display the destination of files openend? LsaEnumerateLogonSessions?

Comment: Yes, the lsaEnumerateLogonSessions does not display the file destinations. However, there is a visual basic script that ties File_Info_3 and Session_Info_502, i have pasted it here, http://pastebin.com/E5W2SXXL.

Comment: I guess I didn't express myself very well, sorry. What I mean was, that you have to do "two" steps: **1)** Using the function you still have to retrieve the 'username' and find the open file handles and **2)** to expose the 'IP/Host' for each entry by mapping the 'username' from your first result from the `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` + `LsaGetLogonSessionData(logonSessionId)` evaulation of all currently logged in usersessions.

Comment: Could you show an example, because the way that I am doing it is using `NetSessionEnum(0)` and then looping the computernames in the `NetFileEnum(3,None,None,computer_name)`, but for some reason python doesnt show the computer name, in visual basic and c++/c it does.